# Seperate steps in stepper into different files

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to make each step will be in another `dart` file. (Steps contains a lot of code, it's hard to maintain it in single file)

**What is the idea?**

1. Create `Scaffold` with `stepper` (parent widget)
2. Parent widget creates an instance of steps, each instance modifies the same model (object of class)
3. Parent widget may call `isValid()` method on each step. (if it's valid, we can switch to next step)

**Requirements**:

- Steps may be `StatefulWidget` or `StatelessWidget` (it may be hard to achieve so StatefulWidget will be enough)
- Each step should contain `bool isValid()` method.

What I have? - Almost nothing

```
abstract class ValidatedStep {
  bool isValid();
}
```

And see below `Step`, we implement this `abstract class` into `Step1`, but this method should ask `state` if it's valid. From `StatefulWidget` we do not have access to state.

```
class Step1 extends StatefulWidget implements ValidatedStep {
  //its ok to create it here?
  final _Step1State state = _Step1State();

  @override
  _Step1State createState() {
    //we could (and should?) create state here, but variables in this widget should be final 
    return state;
  }

  @override
  bool isValid() {
    return state.isValid();
  }
}

class _Step1State extends State<Step1> implements ValidatedStep {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }

  @override
  bool isValid() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map.. Here is a modified example of my code.. Perhaps you can modify to add function to validate the steps.

You can simply put the different Widget from different files in the list.

```
class StepperScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<SomeClass> list;
  StepperScreen({@required this.list});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'Stepper Screen',
          ),
        ),
        body: Stepper(
          steps: getStep(list),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<Step> getStep(List<SomeClass> list) {
  return list
      .map(
        (e) => Step(
          title: Text(
            e.name,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
          ),
          content: e.child,
        ),
      )
      .toList();
}
```

Of course, your SomeClass should have the properties:

```
class SomeClass {
    String name;
    Widget child;

SomeClass({@required this.name, @required this.child});

}
```

Comment: How to ask this statefull widget, if its valid? :)

Comment: what kind of thing do you want to check for validation?

Comment: i have no idea what you want to do with the isValid(). 

But, if you want to populate only screen with certain properties, maybe you can filter the original list first, and then populate based on the new list. If you want all the child widget having access to the isvalid() method, maybe you can use providers to do that.

Comment: From parent I could call `bool isValid()` to child steps and then I get to know that form or something other conditions are fine

Comment: I have edited answer, please check the code of `Step1`

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but instead of asking the step if it `isValid()` pass some callback e.g. `onReadyChange(bool)` down to the step and call it from within the step according to your business logic.